# pygame screen loop not working correctly. loop keeps reshreshing unlike others

Tags: python, pygame

```py
def selection():
    global selectionLoop 
    selectionLoop = True
    clock.tick(1)
    while selectionLoop:
        print("disspam")
        window.blit(backgroundgame, (0,0)) 
        text.title('CHOOSE A SUBJECT!') 
        button(550, 500, 250, 100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'MUSIC', 'music', black, smallText) 
        button(900, 500, 250, 100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'ART', 'art', black, smallText) 
        button(1250, 500, 250, 100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'DRAMA', 'drama', black, smallText)
        pygame.display.update()
```

This menu works correctly, when i press instructions it works as well but when I press selection it spams the loop and doesn't listen to the mouse

```py
def menu(): 
    pygame.mixer.music.load("menu_music.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    mainLoop = True 
    clock.tick(1) 
    while mainLoop: 

        window.blit(background, (0,0)) 

        text.title('lettermatcher.edu') 
        
        button(550, 500, 250, 100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'SELECTION', 'selction', black, smallText) 
        button(900, 500, 250, 100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'INSTRUCTIONS', 'rule', black, smallText) 
        button(1250, 500, 250, 100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'QUIT', 'end', black, smallText)

        pygame.display.update()
```

https://www.mediafire.com/file/5n0hkva5alqawiz/pygame.zip/file
so this is my game, feel free to download it and it has the problem when going into the selection menu with going straight into the game. When in the selection function it spams the loop like all the other screens but doesn't display it. can someone please help me fix this.

Comment: You have to add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: can’t you just run the code i uploaded in mediafile

Comment: No. You have to show the code (snippet) which bothers you. Stackoverflow is not a debug service. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok thanks when i get on my computer i can, it’s under the function, selections

Answer (score 0):

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Minimal and working example:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# main application loop
run = True
while run:
    # limit frames per second
    clock.tick(100)

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # clear the display
    window.fill(0)

    # draw the scene   
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 0, 0), (250, 250), 100)

    # update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```